# Stripe recurrent charges for 3D secured cards (not subscription or billing)

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I want customer to pass 3D secure process only once. Then his future charges should be proceeded without doing 3d secure process. Is it possible in stripe? It is not clear from documentation. If it is possible then what is wrong my flow?

1. Add card to customer and get card source id
2. Create 3d source id using customer id and card source id

   ```
   source = stripe.Source.create(
   amount=1099,
   currency="eur",
   type='three_d_secure',
   three_d_secure={
       'card': card source id,
       'customer': customer id
   },
   redirect={
       'return_url': 'https://shop.example.com/crtA6B28E1'
   },
   ```

   )
3. Then by passing to url I do 3d secure authentication, and 3d secure source authenticated becomes "true".
4. I make charge using 3d secure source id and customer id and it succeeds.

   ```
   charge = stripe.Charge.create(
       amount=1099,
       currency='eur',
       customer=customer id,
       source='3d secure source id'
   )
   ```
5. Then I try to make charge using just customer and it fails.

   ```
   charge = stripe.Charge.create(
       amount=1099,
       currency='eur',
       customer=customer id
   )
   ```

Comment: You have to charge the oriiginal card(`card source ID`) and not the 3DS source([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure/subscriptions)), so make sure that one is the customer's default source. BUT — this won't work for cards that have `three_d_secure:required`, like the 4000000000003063 test card. For those, you *have to* create a new 3DS source and do the authorization redirect and charge the new 3DS source, for _every_ charge, or they fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Card with 3d secure `required` have to be authorized by user *every* charge.